# Windows AppFabric ACS with AD FS 2.0, help using the AcmBrowser.exe

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, azure, appfabric

There seems to be very limited information floating around the net about this and I wondered if someone here may be able to help out.

I'm running the AcmBrowser.exe to integrate AD FS 2.0 with AppFabric (ACS), yet the authentication service as default tries to point to accesscontrol.windows.net, which is an unaccessible domain and the AppFabric labs resolve to accesscontrol.appfabriclabs.com - so is this a case of the AcmBrowser not being updated by Microsoft?

I've changed the URL in the AcmBrowser code and run the program, in which now comes back as invalid token issuer - when I've taken the management key directly from the ACS (Administration -> Management service -> Management client -> Symmetric Key?).

Is there anyone out there that's facesd this issue before? I believe it's the last step I need to take of syncing my AD FS 2.0 with ACS + Relying Party.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the AcmBrowser was built for ACS v1.0 (the current production version of ACS). I don't know if the tool will be updated or not for V2 (currently in "labs"), but I'm pretty certain the API in ACS V2 is different from V1.

You will have to use the new portal (or the new API) if you want to use ACS v2.

What kind of app are you configuring? A web site? a Service (rest/soap)? Depending on the app there might be slight variations on configuration, but using the portal it should be very straight forward.

Also (just a small detail), there's no "synching" between ADFS v2 and ACS, just a trust relationship.

Comment: I got all thsi sorted out yesterday thankfully, with you being 100% correct - there's VERY limited information out there if you want to use the Labs environment and syncing this up with RP -> AppFabric 2.0 -> AD FS2.0 but managed to get it all sorted in the end!